# Android Eclipse project having Google+ and Facebook login when imported to Android Studio does not work. Login functionality fails

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-plus-signin, android-studio-import

I have an Android project created in Eclipse which uses google play services and Facebook `sdk` libraries to login through google+ and Facebook. When I import this project to Android Studio and generate an `apk`, the google+ and Facebook login do not work.
They work fine in the apk generated by Eclipse however. I am not sure what causes this problem, the way use google services has changed in Android Studio and it just requires adding a dependency instead of adding the library. I searched this topic but could not find someone with the same problem. I need to know what changes to make in the project so it works properly. 
Any help is highly appreciated.
Current dependencies in the imported project.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile project(':dateTimePickerMaterialLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: No error. It does nothing actually. The google plus sign in offers to choose an account, but after choosing the account nothing happens.

Comment: May be the problem due to studio and eclipse using different keystore So I think you should update your sha finger print in google console.

Comment: And in facebook keyhash